# why if the number I enter gets to high it returns the wrong number

Tags: winapi, assembly, x86, masm

I've got the following code but I can't work out why if the number I enter is too high does it return the wrong number. It might be because of the data types and dividing and multiplying but I can't work out exactly why. if you know of why I would be grateful for the help.

```
.586
.model flat, stdcall
option casemap :none
.stack 4096
extrn ExitProcess@4: proc

GetStdHandle proto :dword
ReadConsoleA  proto :dword, :dword, :dword, :dword, :dword
WriteConsoleA proto :dword, :dword, :dword, :dword, :dword
STD_INPUT_HANDLE equ -10
STD_OUTPUT_HANDLE equ -11

.data

    bufSize = 80
    inputHandle DWORD ?
    buffer db bufSize dup(?)
    bytes_read  DWORD  ?
    sum_string db "The number was ",0
    outputHandle DWORD ?
    bytes_written dd ?
    actualNumber dw 0
    asciiBuf db 4 dup (0)
.code
  main:

    invoke GetStdHandle, STD_INPUT_HANDLE
    mov inputHandle, eax
    invoke ReadConsoleA, inputHandle, addr buffer, bufSize, addr bytes_read,0
    sub bytes_read, 2   ; -2 to remove cr,lf
    mov ebx,0

    mov al, byte ptr buffer+[ebx] 
    sub al,30h
    add [actualNumber],ax
getNext:
    inc bx
    cmp ebx,bytes_read
    jz cont
    mov ax,10
    mul [actualNumber]
    mov actualNumber,ax
    mov al, byte ptr buffer+[ebx] 
    sub al,30h
    add actualNumber,ax

    jmp getNext
cont:


    invoke GetStdHandle, STD_OUTPUT_HANDLE
    mov outputHandle, eax
    mov eax,LENGTHOF sum_string ;length of sum_string
    invoke WriteConsoleA, outputHandle, addr sum_string, eax, addr bytes_written, 0
    mov ax,[actualNumber]
    mov cl,10
    mov bl,3
nextNum:
    xor edx, edx
    div cl
    add ah,30h
    mov byte ptr asciiBuf+[ebx],ah
    dec ebx
    mov ah,0
    cmp al,0
    ja nextNum

    mov eax,4

    invoke WriteConsoleA, outputHandle, addr asciiBuf, eax, addr bytes_written, 0

    mov eax,0
    mov eax,bytes_written
    push    0

    call    ExitProcess@4
end     main
```

Comment: Microsoft has a nice debugger in its Visual Studio environment. [Ollydbg](http://www.ollydbg.de/) works okay too.

Comment: You don't really give us much to go on when you say "too high" and "wrong number." As a guess I'd imagine that you're trying to use a number that is larger than the size that you have designed your code to handle.

Answer (score 2):

Yes, it is plausible that your return value is capped by a maximum value. This maximum is either the `BYTE` boundary of 255 or the `WORD` boundary of 65536. Let me explain why, part by part:

```
mov inputHandle, eax
invoke ReadConsoleA, inputHandle, addr buffer, bufSize, addr bytes_read,0
sub bytes_read, 2   ; -2 to remove cr,lf
mov ebx,0

mov al, byte ptr buffer+[ebx] 
sub al,30h
add [actualNumber],ax
```

In this part you are calling a `Win32 API` function, which always returns the `return` value in the register `EAX`. After it has returned, you assign the lower 8-bits of the 32-bit return value to `byte ptr buffer+[ebx]`, subtract `30h` from it. Then you `MOV` the 8-bit you just modified in `AL` and the 8-bit from the return-value preserved in `AH` as a block `AX` to a `WORD` variable by `add [actualNumber],ax`. So `AH` stems from the `EAX` return value and is quite of `undefined`. You may be lucky if it's `0`, but that should not be assumed.

The next problem is the following sub-routine:

```
getNext:
  inc bx
  cmp ebx,bytes_read
  jz cont
  mov ax,10
  mul [actualNumber]
  mov actualNumber,ax
  mov al, byte ptr buffer+[ebx] 
  sub al,30h
  add actualNumber,ax
  jmp getNext
```

You are moving the decimal base `10` to the `WORD` register `AX` and multiply it by the `WORD` variable `[actualNumber]`. So far, so good. But the result of a 16-bit*16-bit `MUL` is returned in the register pair `AX:DX`(lower:higher). So your `mov actualNumber,ax` solely `MOV`s the lower 16-bits to your variable (`DX` is ignored, limiting your result to `result % 65536`). So your maximum possible result is MAX_WORD = 65535. Everything else would just give you the modulo in `AX`.

After your `mov al, byte ptr buffer+[ebx]` your overwrite the lower 8-bits of this result with the `BYTE` pointed to by `buffer[ebx]` and then subtract `30h` from it. Remember: the higher 8-bits of the result still remain in AH, the higher 8-bits of AX.

Then you (re)add this value to the variable `actualNumber` with `add actualNumber,ax`. Let me condense these last two paragraphs:

```
Operation                        |        AX        |
                                 |  AL          AH  |
mov actualNumber,ax              | ................ |
mov al, byte ptr buffer+[ebx]    | ........     AH  |
sub al,30h                       | ....-30h     AH  |
add actualNumber,ax              | ................ |
```

So, you are modifying the lower 8-bits of `AX` through `AL` and then add the higher 8-bits of `actualNumber`/`AH` to itself - effectively doubling `AH` and then adding this to `actualNumber` like this:

```
actualNumber = 256 * (2 * AH) + (byte ptr buffer[ebx]-30h)      ; I doubt you want that ;-)
```

These problems may cause several deviations from the desired result.

Comment: Thank you for your help, but I don't understand actualNumber = 256 * (2 * AH) + (byte ptr buffer[ebx]-30h)

Comment: @dummieadam: It's quite simple: `AX` is (256*AH)+AL. Or in another notation: `AX=AH*256+AL`. To put it in another way: a 16-bit value like `AX`does consist of two 8-bit values (`AH` and `AL`) and the "higher" 8-bits are "weighted" by 2^8=256. So `AX(16-bit) = AH(8-bit)*256 + AL(8-bit)`.